# Save pbm ascii to pbm binary c++

Tags: c++, image-processing

I have file pbm P1 (ascii)

```
P1
#Created by Venom 
2 2 
1 0 
0 1
```

And I want to convert it as P4 (pbm binary). How I can do this?

i have pixel array of int

```
int pixel[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
```

I need convert it to binary array here

```
for (int i =0; i < HEIGHT ; i++)
     {
         for (int j =0; j < WIDTH; j++)
         {

             }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to write your own converter, or just looking for a tool that will do the necessary conversion, or looking to write a program that outputs a binary pbm?

Comment: It's a pretty simple format.  Should be easy enough to figure out.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format

Comment: did u read the question? i dont know how to convert

Comment: I did, and I linked a page where the format is described.  This isn't a "write code for me" site, you'll need to try on your own and you are welcome to ask any specific questions you have along the way.

Comment: and how i can packing 8 pixels per byte?

Comment: Write some code showing that you can read the ascii version and store the data then post that code and ask for help packing it properly.

Comment: i have array of pixels in int, and i need byte array

Comment: I have each in array pixel[i][j] and i need to convert each pixel to binary? or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for the files I was able to find to test it with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct PBM
{
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    std::string comment;
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> data;

    bool ReadAscii(std::ifstream& f)
    {
        std::string id;
        if(!std::getline(f, id) || id != "P1")
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(f.peek() == '#' && !std::getline(f, comment))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!(f >> width >> height))
        {
            return false;
        }
        data.resize(height);
        int temp;
        for(size_t y = 0; y < data.size(); ++y)
        {
            data[y].resize(width);
            for(size_t x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                if(!(f >> temp))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                data[y][x] = static_cast<char>(temp);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool WriteBinary(std::ofstream& f)
    {
        if(!(f << "P4\n"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!comment.empty() && !(f << comment << "\n"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!(f << width << " " << height << "\n"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        std::vector<char> linebits((width + (CHAR_BIT - 1)) / CHAR_BIT);
        for(size_t y = 0; y < data.size(); ++y)
        {
            std::fill(linebits.begin(), linebits.end(), 0);
            for(size_t x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                const int byte_pos = x / CHAR_BIT;
                const int bit_pos = (CHAR_BIT - 1) - (x % CHAR_BIT);
                linebits[byte_pos] |= (data[y][x] << bit_pos);
            }
            if(!f.write(&linebits[0], linebits.size()))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: convertpbm <ascii filename> <binary filename>\n";
        return 0;
    }

    PBM pbm;

    std::ifstream inFile(argv[1]);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open '" << argv[1] << "' for input!\n";
        return 0;
    }
    if(!pbm.ReadAscii(inFile))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error reading input file!\n";
    }

    std::ofstream outFile(argv[2], std::ios::binary);
    if(!outFile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open '" << argv[1] << "' for output!\n";
        return 0;
    }
    if(!pbm.WriteBinary(outFile))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error writing output file!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: converter to byte not work, i
have this effect http://imghost.in/img/2013-11/23/exngc12dyrh6hblbkn1onajd1.jpg

Comment: It worked for every source file I tried and I wasn't able to find an image of Lena that looked like that one.  Are you testing only my code or something else?

Comment: I found a 512x512 grayscale version of Lena, converted it to black and white with IrfanView and saved it as an ascii PBM.  My program converted it to a binary pbm with no issues.  Without seeing your actual code I'm afraid I can't help you.