# Reading ppm file C++

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ppm

I am trying to read a ppm file and store its contents in an array. I am starting off by trying to display it but I can't seem to output anything.

```
char magic;
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open(file,ios::in | ios::binary);
  if (!myfile.is_open()) 
   {
      cout<<"Failed to open";
   }
myfile.get(magic);
if(myfile) cout <<magic <<"not working";
myfile.close();
```

The file is opened but I can't read it. I have also tried outputting by using the << operators, but no luck there either.

Comment: When you say you "can't read it", what do you mean? Do you see nothing when you cout << magic?

Comment: What type of PPM?  What's the magic number you're expecting, P1 -> P6?

Comment: This answer may help you see how to read the header, but without knowing what type of file you're dealing with I can't give you advice on how to read the actual image data.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20092028/920069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probable that your file is being read, but your variable isn't storing all the values therein. I suggest adding this instead of myfile.get(magic):

```
char magic;
ifstream myfile;

if (!myfile.open(file, ios::in | ios::binary)
{
    cout << "Failed to open" << endl;
}

vector<char> magicNumbers;
while (myfile >> magic)
{
    magicNumbers.push_back(magic);
}
myfile.close();
```

As you can see, you should store all the values in some kind of array, here I used a vector for flexibility. The rest is up to you.

Comment: That worked fine although I think I also had a problem with my ppm photo so I downloaded a new one. Thank you @Vormeph!

Comment: Sorry just one more question @Vormeph, can you explain what "while (myfile >> magic)" is doing?

Comment: All it does is read every character from the file including spaces into the variable 'char magic'. You don't have to do it this way, but it's shorter the way I've done it. See getline(...) if you want another way.